# QT : has no member named 'setModal'

Tags: c++, windows, qt

Salam Alikom

i have to windows in my project (login.ui and menu.ui)
there is a push_button on the first windows
i want to make this button open the other window "menu.ui" when is clicked ()

i did this code in push_button function

```
Menu menu;
menu.setModal(true);
menu.exec();
```

but it doesn't work and give this error :

```
C:\Users\Amine\Documents\QT\E-LogBook\login.cpp:43: erreur : 'class Menu' has no member named 'setModal'
 menu.setModal(true);
      ^
```

Comment: A `QMenu` has no setModal(). Why do you want a modal menu instead of a modal dialog??

Comment: Wait a minute you are going to have to post your header for `Menu`. How do we know what its parent is?

Comment: It appears that *"'class Menu' has no member named 'setModal'"*. What is your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. There is a little bit more to it than that. Try creating a new project and following along from my steps:

Open up the mainwindow.ui and drag the pushButton onto the ui. Right click the push button and select "Go to slot...". From here, you should see a list of all triggering actions. Select "clicked()".

This will generate a nice piece of code in mainwindow.cpp to deal with the event of a click on the pushbutton. It should look like the following:

```
      void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
      {

      }
```

Next, right click on the Forms folder in the project tree to the left of the text editing window. Select "Add New..."->"Qt"->"Qt Designer Form Class"->"choose..."->"Dialog without buttons" and then name it whatever you want. I called mine "MyDialog".

This generate mydialog.ui, mydialog.cpp, and mydialog.h. We want the MainWindow class to be a parent to the MyDialog class. So we go to mainwindow.h and insert

```
    #include "mydialog.h"
```

and then we go to the private: section of mainwindow.h and create a pointer to a MyDialog object.
Change the MainWindow class private block to read:

```
    private:
        Ui::MainWindow *ui;
        MyDialog *mDialog;
```

So now we have a pointer to the MyDialog class included within the MainWindow class.

Next, go to mainwindow.cpp and change the event method to read:

```
    void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
    {
        mDialog = new MyDialog(this); // allocated space for a new MyDialog
                                     // while also giving a parent class of 
                                     // this, the MainWindow class
        mDialog->show(); // call the show method on the object
    }
```

Voila! You did it!